# When using 'Close' through "Tools", system does not appear to register vote

Tags: bug, review, closing

When you use the 'Review', 'Tools', it will sometimes have a 'Close' option if someone flagged it as a duplicate.

When you use this 'Close', it displays a message that it counted your close vote, but when you check that, it does not appear to register that vote.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Note: The same issue occurs when you are reviewing posts and there is a close(x) and you use to immediately vote for closure - the vote is not counted.